# Toys for disinterested cat

Tags: cats, toys

My cat tends to be apathetic to toys. When I bring out the fishing rod, he initially chases after it, but then stays still and doesn't do stuff. The sole exception is normally when I drag the mouse on the end behind something, then he gets interest and pounces on it. I found that he likes yarn more, and I particularly like the fact that while the cat has one part of the yarn, you could bring up another thread for him to get interest. He loves getting high off catnip toys as well. I also know he plays with small fuzzy balls at night, and sometimes he pounces on him when I throw them over his head

I was wondering what other toys might interest such a disinterested cat. Any recommendations? Only toys I can't do are most balls because my cat and dog have a mutual understanding that balls are usually automatically the dog's (guess how I got that clump of yarn)

Comment: Welcome to Pets.SE! I only understand that you want your cat to lay with toys. But what is the actual problem? Bad health? He does not eat, sleep? What breed is he? What age? Please use the EDIT button and add all these details to your question, so we can understand the problem.

Comment: My cat is healthy. Just want to make him happier. I'm curious what other toys might be worth trying, as he tends to be disinterested for the most part

Comment: What makes you think he's unhappy?

Comment: He's not unhappy, and is in fact pretty happy. It sounds like what I should do is go to PetsMart and see what sort of stuff they have there

Comment: @gist076923: my feeling right now is that you should start being happy yourself. Just sit down, relax, and enjoy being around your friend. You know what they say... Don't fix it if it is not broken. ;)

Comment: Have you seen [this](https://pets.stackexchange.com/q/36793/16350) Q/A?

Comment: I didn't see that Q and A. Thanks for the link

Comment: How old is kitty? Not all cats remain big toy-players as they get older.

Comment: A few years old. Three or four I think

Answer (score 1):

My experience is that some cats have never learned how to play with toys, so they won't be interested in them, no matter which kind you try.

However, certain instincts are ingrained in all cats and I used that to develop a simple game with my cat. I simply throw individual pieces of her dry food and let her "hunt" them.

First you need to get your cat interested in the kibble in your hand. I found that cats are very sensitive to slight scratching noises, probably because rodents often make such noises. So I hold a piece of kibble in my hand and lightly scratch my finger nail over the floor. As soon as I have the attention of my cat, I throw the kibble so low that it skips over the ground (like a running mouse). I aim for a path that passes right in front of her. That triggers her hunting instinct and she pounces the kibble. The reward (having a snack) is already build into this game.

My cat took some time to understand the game and sometimes, when she's not in the mood, she lazily walks to the kibble and eats it without playing at all. Most of the time she loses interest after just 10 repetitions, but in the end she was more active and that's my main goal.

Comment: Ha! That’s “the” game for our old cat well. If the treat doesn’t fly wide enough, he’ll often give it an extra smack just to get it flying again. And he’s pretty calm and relaxed (some would call him lazy). As cats are hunters that stalk their prey, not chase it down, 10-20 repetitions is usually enough for him to tire him out.

Comment: That sounds like a good idea. As in my other comment, gotta make sure dog doesn't get involved

Comment: @gist076923 or it's also a training session for the dog - staying put even if there's temptation.

Answer (score 1):

Two alternatives outside of the usual “toys” line of thought if your goal is to provide enrichment (beyond Elmy’s “chase the treat”):

Clicker Training.
Yes, cats can learn tricks like dogs and the mechanics are pretty much the same. There are lots of resources available. The benefits are mental stimulation and a very intense interaction - you can’t do clicker training without being fully focused.

Hiding treats / fiddle boxes / snuffle mats.
Treats can be hidden in different places and objects, ultimately encouraging the cat to either try and grab it with their paw (boxes with holes, empty rolls or TP with half-closed ends…) or find by smell (snuffle mats, boxes with shredded paper or packaging peanuts). The latter can also lead to happy digging and other kinds of play. The benefit is that these kinds of activities don’t require human presence and can be prepared in advance and pulled out as needed.

Comment: I did try to see if the cat would interact with the clump of yarn itself if I put a catnip mouse in it. Perhaps I should try putting his favorite treat in it. I do have to be careful that the dog doesn't get involved

Comment: Yes, that could be an issue - the dog probably would like to "share" the treat.

Answer (score 0):

My cat, who’s fourteen, loves to play with toys, but I’ve found his tastes change from soft toys to hard one. When he becomes disinterested, I switch to the other type of toy.

Hard toys he likes look like large springs with a rubbery coating and hard plastic swirls (like a candy cane if you removed one color!). You mentioned not wanting balls, but the hard plastic balls with a bell inside are also big hits.

Remember that cats are patient hunters and will sit, watching, for quite a while before pouncing.

I once read that cats will play for ten minutes, take a short rest, play for about five minutes, and be done. I’ve found this is very true with my cat, so I play accordingly. Patience is key!